# My shell script is giving me the wrong output

Tags: linux, shell-script, fedora-23

I have created a script that is supposed to (in the below section) store the name and location of their corresponding values in an assigned variable, then list the name variables in a column. I have successfully done this before, but for some reason all I am getting are empty lines. Please help me because I can't seem to make heads or tails of this problem.

```
#This is where sections are added or removed
#SECTIONnumberNAME=$(echo "number: section name")
#SECTIONnumberLOCARION=./Setup_Fedora_Sections/section_name.sh

SECTION1NAME=$(echo "1: Wireless Card")
SECTION1LOCARION=./Setup_Fedora_Sections/Setup_Fedora_Wireless_Card.sh
SECTION2NAME=$(echo "2: Basic Setup")
SECTION2LOCARION=./Setup_Fedora_Sections/Setup_Fedora_Basic_Setup.sh
SECTION3NAME=$(echo "3: Optional Programs")
SECTION3LOCARION=./Setup_Fedora_Sections/Setup_Fedora_Optional_Programs.sh

#This is where selection offers are added or removed
#echo $'\n'$SELECTIONnumberNAME
echo $'\n'$SELECTION1NAME
echo $'\n'$SELECTION2NAME
echo $'\n'$SELECTION3NAME
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `variable=$(echo text)` instead of `variable=text`?

Comment: Often it is cosy to copy and past always (or never) the variable name to avoid to make errors...  You are printing empty variables (`$SE `LE`CTIONxNAME` and not `$SECTIONxNAME`). Moreover to debug a script you can write `set -` (and `set +`) at the beginning (and the end) of the part to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try changing the text "SELECTION" in the later part of the script to be "SECTION" to match the first part of the script. It looks like a simple spelling issue. So, this works for me:

```
#This is where selection offers are added or removed
#echo $'\n'$SELECTIONnumberNAME
echo $'\n'$SECTION1NAME
echo $'\n'$SECTION2NAME
echo $'\n'$SECTION3NAME
```

Comment: Wow thanks it so easy to miss those differences, thanks for pointing my oversight out.

Comment: just out of curiosity is there a way to make the above correction into a variable and have it display the same way and not on one line?

Comment: There are probably several changes I would personally make if that were my code. First, I would go with AFH's recommendation and simply use `variable="value"`. But I think that what you are looking for would be an array. Also, when doing the echo, I wouldn't do `$'\n'`, but instead would do something like `echo -e "\n$variable1\n$variable2\n"`.

Comment: whats the difference between the two methods?

Comment: The first one is more obvious. Simply assigning text to a variable directly is easy, and instant. Trying to create a subshell and run a separate command and then piping that output into the variable takes resources, and it's longer to write. As for the last part, it's just convenience and preference. Rather than having to have multiple commands, you can have one, and you only need a single string. It's also fewer characters to type.